# Google earth polygon area measure Vs. Arc GIS Polygon Area Measure

Tags: c#, arcgis, google-earth

I have a Kml file(Google earth file) that contains million of Polygon,

I want to add each Polygon area to it's Description by c#,

I founded some good formula to calculate Polygon area like :

```
    private Double polygonArea(int[] x, int[] y) {      
    Double area = 0.0;
    int j = x.length-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        area = area + (x[j]+x[i]) * (y[j]-y[i]);
        j = i;
    }
    area = area/2;
    if (area < 0)
        area = area * -1;
    return area;
}
```

And also I used ArC GIS SDK 10 to calculate Polygon area:
(it's a bad code but it's just an example):

```
    PolygonClass pPntColl;
    pPntColl = new PolygonClass();
    IPoint point;
    point = new Point();

    point.PutCoords(57.63235013024734, 36.21563171159841);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
    point.PutCoords(57.63237322461755, 36.2157698149511);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
    point.PutCoords(57.6323553756371, 36.21586604544851);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
    point.PutCoords(57.63226615527618, 36.21600871152099);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
    point.PutCoords(57.63218330336011, 36.21595817513495);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
    point.PutCoords(57.63141107098331, 36.21577622377622);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
    point.PutCoords(57.63144168230467, 36.21556194876793);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
    point.PutCoords(57.63235013024734, 36.21563171159841);
    pPntColl.AddPoint(point);
```

All is ok but there is a problem.
Google Earth pro calculate different area

for example, Google shown above polygon area : 2699 
But Arc GIS and Formula : 2705 .

I want my program calculate same area as Google earth .

is any solution?

Comment: The formula you are using treats the coordinates as cartesian coordinates but they are actually geographical coordinates. Therefore, the result of your formula will be different than what you find in ArcGIS or Google Earth.  Take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/, you may find a lot of useful information there.

Comment: thanks, I think Kml file use UTM coordinate system but is use decimal, by converting decimal to UTM , my program calculate area correctly Most of the time , but big polygon still have problem ,but It is just a 1 Square meter differences.